# Program works but off a little. Java Simple Payroll Program

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the total payout to all employees but it is still taking the original salary for employee1 instead of the salary after the hours are increased by 10. Please advise on what I am doing wrong.

```
package payroll;

public class Payroll 
{
    private static double totalSalary ;

    private String id ;
    private double hours ;
    private double rate ;
    private double salary ;

    public Payroll(String id, double hours, double rate)
    {
        this.id = id ;
        this.hours = hours ;
        this.rate = rate ;
        double salaryCalc = hours * rate ;
        totalSalary = totalSalary + salaryCalc ;
    }

    public void calculateSalary()
    {
        salary = hours * rate ;
    }

    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary ;
    }

    public String getEmployeeID()
    {
        return id ;
    }

    public double getHours()
    {
        return hours ;
    }

    public double getRate()
    {
        return rate ;
    }

    public void increaseHours(double hourIncrease) 
    {
        hours = hours + hourIncrease ;
    }

    public static double getTotalPayout()
    {
        return totalSalary ;
    }
}
```

TEST CLASS

```
package payroll;

import java.util.Date ;         // Used for creating a Date object
import java.text.DateFormat ;   // Used for specifying the format of the date
import java.text.NumberFormat ; // Used for specifying the type of currency



public class TestPayroll 
    {       
        public static void main(String [] arg)
        {
        // Set up the formatters
        Date d = new Date(2010-1900, 8-1, 25) ; // Date Class requires these adjustments to get proper date
        //Date d = new Date() ; // if current date was required
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG) ;
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() ;

        System.out.println("\nPayroll For Week Ending " + df.format(d)) ;
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        Payroll employee1 = new Payroll("444-4444", 30, 25) ;
        employee1.calculateSalary() ;
        displaySalary(employee1, nf) ;

        Payroll employee2 = new Payroll("555-5555", 20, 50) ;
        employee2.calculateSalary() ;
        displaySalary(employee2, nf) ;

        System.out.println("\tIncrease " + employee1.getEmployeeID() + " by 10 hours") ;
        employee1.increaseHours(10) ; 
        employee1.calculateSalary() ;
        displaySalary(employee1, nf) ;

        System.out.println("Total payout amount.. " +  nf.format(Payroll.getTotalPayout())) ;
        System.out.println("------------ End of report ----------") ;
        }


        public static void displaySalary(Payroll e, NumberFormat nf)    
        {
        System.out.println("\tEmployee # ......" + e.getEmployeeID() ) ;
        System.out.println("\tHours Worked ...." + e.getHours() + " hours" ) ;
        System.out.println("\tHourly Rate ....." + nf.format(e.getRate()) + "/hour" ) ;
        System.out.println("\tYour Salary is .." + nf.format(e.getSalary()) ) ;
        System.out.println("\t---------------------------------\n") ;
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? In the total calc? that shouldn't be done in the constructor, but done on the fly using a collection of Employees. Also, I'd get rid of the `calculateSalary()` method and the salary field, and instead would calculate the salary on the fly inside the `getSalary()` method.

Comment: I agree with calculateSalary() being changed but this is what the teacher wants. Not getting an error. The total payout should be $2000 not $1750.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean to change the static fields values

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't calculate the addition to the total payout in the class's constructor since changes to its state will not be reflected in this field (as you're discovering). If you had to do it in the constructor, you'd need to have your class implement an observer type design to notify outside classes of change -- something you don't want or need. Instead, I'd create a collection of Employee objects (that's what I'd name the class), and iterate through the collection to calculate totalPayout with a for loop whenever it is needed.

e.g.,

```
public class Employee {
    private double hours;
    private double rate;

    public Employee(double hours, double rate) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return hours * rate;
    }

    // method to change hours, get rate, get hours, etc...
}
```

and:

```
public class Payroll {
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    public double getTotalPayout() {
        double totalSalary = 0;
        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            totalSalary += employee.getSalary();
        }
        return totalSalary;
    }

    // methods for adding Employee objects to list, for getting Employee...
    // etc...
}
```

---

Edit: based on your assignment requirements, then you must change totalSalary and totalHours within

1) the constructor and
2) the `increaseHours` method.

I would have a calculateSalary method yes, and call it from within increaseHours to incrementally increase the value of totalHours and totalSalary.

Comment: We are not allowed to use loops or arrays unfortunately

Comment: @Kyle: Please let's end all ambiguity. Please post your *exact and complete* requirements.

Comment: Write a Java program that can be used to calculate the weekly salary for hourly paid employees. The program initially accepts the employee’s id, the number of hours worked, and the hourly pay rate. An employee may work additional hours. When this happens, the additional number of hours must be added to the original amount, and the salary is recalculated. The program must output on separate lines the employee’s id number, the number of hours worked, the hourly pay rate, and the salary, for each employee. In addition, the program must also output the total amount of money paid out by the company

Comment: In designing your program consider the following:
(a) Write a class called Payroll to include, but not limited to:
• Instance variables for number of hours worked, and hourly rate of pay.
• Class variable for accumulating the weekly payroll.
• A mutator instance method that calculates an employee salary, and accumulates the weekly payroll.
• Constructor that accepts the employee’s id number, the number of hours worked, and the hourly rate per employee.

(b) Design a test class called TestPayroll that implements the Payroll class. See Listing 1 for incomplete definition of the test class.

Comment: @Kyle: where is there mention of not using ArrayLists?

Comment: he said in class because he hasn't taught it

Comment: Then change the values of the static field within the constructor **and** the increaseHours method.

Comment: public void increaseHours(double hourIncrease) 
    {
        hours = hours + hourIncrease ;
        double salaryCalc = hours * rate ;
        totalSalary = totalSalary + salaryCalc ;      
    }

Comment: I did this and now I get $1000 but how would I get the other employee

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean to change the static fields values

Comment: Handle an unknown number of inputs without looping?  I'll admit I'm impressed --- not many professors dive straight into recursion so quickly.

Comment: @Kyle "Static field" is a synonym for "class variable" (more or less, at least in this case).

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I can not get this to run the way it is supposed to still